# find arguments generated by for loop through array?

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, find

I write a bash script to search through directories using the find command with different `-iname` arguments.
I want to pass `-iname` arguments to the find command by using a for loop. The strings for the `-iname` arguments are stored in an array.
I want to loop through the arguments to generate `-iname ${arr[$i]} -or` expressions.
Finally I add a single `-iname ${arr[${#v_end[@]}-1]}`  argument without `-or`

The final find command should be like

`find -L $destDir (-iname "*.mp4" -or -iname "*.AVI -or -iname "*.MTS")`

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
destDir= '/share/Multimedia2/VideoLink/tmp'
v_end=("mp4" "AVI" "MTS");
arr_len=${#v_end[@]};
arr_len=(($arr_len--))

find -L $destDir \(( for ( i=0; i<$arr_len; i++); do ( -iname "${v_end[$i]} -or" ) done ) -iname "${v_end[$arr_len]}" \)
```

This doesn't work. What do I have to do to pass the for loop results to the find command?

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". If you still have a problem afterwards make sure to provide a [mcve] with the corrected code plus concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

What you have on the `find` command line doesn’t look like Bash at all.

I wouldn’t recommend expanding the array in one go, mainly because the script should support spaces and a few other (somewhat) common (somewhat) special characters in file names, which is hard to do while expanding an array and interleaving it with other tokens.

One can e.g. prepare the command line as another array and expand that one:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# Prepare some files to search for:
tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
trap 'rm -Rf "$tmpdir"' EXIT
cd "$tmpdir"
touch a b c A B C

# Prepare arguments for find:
inames=(a b c)
find_args=(-false)
for iname in "${inames[@]}"; do
  find_args+=(-or -iname "$iname")
done

# Show and call the find command:
echo find "${find_args[@]}"
find "${find_args[@]}"
```

Comment: this works perfect, thanks!  But I dont unerstand waht `-false` does?

Comment: It does nothing in this case. It just removes the need for special treatment of the first array element. The `find_args` start with `-or` and that is not a valid beginning of a `find` expression. Also, it makes it possible to handle empty `inames` correctly (as we want `find` to find nothing in that case, not to fail with an error).

Comment: An alternate approach: `find_args+=( ${find_args[0]:+ -o } -iname "$iname" )` though this doesn't default to a nice empty result set if there are no `inames` given. ;)

Comment: In your example I figured out that I dont need single or double quotes for the iname argument.  Normally I used quotes  like: `-iname '*.avi'`  or `-iname "*.avi"`. Even if I do not need it in your example, how could I add quotes to your example for the "$iname" in that line: `find_args+=(-or -iname "$iname")`  These quotes in that line are not used in the find command.

Comment: Whenever I tried to add quotes that are "seen" by the find command, I get the error:  "paths must precede expression: ` -or -iname '*.avi''".  or no search result.  This line (with quotes) `find_args+=(-or -iname "'*$iname'")` is promted by echo correctly but finds no results!

Comment: The `find` command should never see any quotes, single or double, unless the quotes are actually present in a file name. Quotes are there for the shell to tokenize things correctly, not for `find` to see. The expansion `"${find_args[@]}"` works as if each array member was quoted. (But then again, no extra quotes are seen by `find`, that’s not how it’s supposed to work.)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be:

```
#!/bin/bash

destDir='/share/Multimedia2/VideoLink/tmp'
v_end=("mp4" "AVI" "MTS")

for ext in "${v_end[@]}"; do
    args+=('-o' '-iname' "*.$ext")
done

find -L "$destDir" \( "${args[@]:1}" \)
```

Comment: The proper option for "or" is simply `-o`. The OP seems to have misspelled it in their original.

Comment: @tripleee Corrected. Thanks. `GNU find` accepts both, though.

Comment: your code almost works, just the first  `-o`. makes problems. I have to get rid of it, bash says:" you have used a binary operator '-or' with nothing before it."

Comment: Is it possible to start the for loop with the 2nd element? Then args could start with `args=" -iname "*.${v_end[0]}""  `. and the for loop would do the rest.

Comment: @Donaufisch My script should work as is. I guess you didn't copy it verbatim.